# SQL split a comma delimited string by fixed length

Tags: sql-server, string, csv, t-sql

I have a string of comma separated values, I am loading these values into a system that has a max length I need to abide by. Once the string hits a max length it should move the values to another column but retain values. For the sake of this example below, I only need to split the string into two columns.

For example my string value = `val1,val2,val3,val4,val5`

Max length of output fields = 15

Output should be two columns:

```
ValueList1             ValueList2
val1,val2,val3         val4,val5
```

I'm trying to complete this with T-SQL but this is not a common issue I need to solve and am stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you care more about performance or maintaining the original sequence of values? You may have to give up one of those.

Comment: Honestly, this would probably perform better in an application, or perhaps with a CLR function.

Comment: Performance is not an issue, not a ton of data and does not need to scale

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 SP4 (11.0.7001.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this.

```
DECLARE @stringvalue VARCHAR(5000) = 'val1,val2,val3,val4,val5'
DECLARE @MaxLengthofOutputFields INT = 15

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN LEN(@stringvalue) > @MaxLengthofOutputFields 
        THEN LEFT(@stringvalue, @MaxLengthofOutputFields - CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(LEFT(@stringvalue,@MaxLengthofOutputFields)))) 
        ELSE @stringvalue END   , 
    CASE WHEN LEN(@stringvalue) > @MaxLengthofOutputFields THEN 
        SUBSTRING(@stringvalue, @MaxLengthofOutputFields - CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(LEFT(@stringvalue,@MaxLengthofOutputFields))) + 2, LEN(@stringvalue)) 
        END
```

Result:

```
-------------------- -------------
val1,val2,val3       val4,val5
```

Comment: I think I should be able to use this, thanks! I tested this with one of my longer strings however and it left a comma at the end of the first output. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: Is it possible to share the string?

Comment: Because, length of the string smaller than maxlength limit. I added a length control to the script

Comment: Great, this is perfect